# How to deploy a React as front and Node as back in Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment

I'm looking in like a hundred pages how to deploy an app with React and Node.js. I just have a form with nodmailer in nodejs. I'm not finding the right way to do it. It's been really difficult to join the 2 programs together.

Comment: Serve your front-end app from your nodejs backend. Deploy it as a node app: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy server and client (react) separately
To deploy react app you will need extra buildpack. Check out [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-deploy-react-app-to-heroku/) link for reference

You can deploy nodejs with buildpack available on heroku.

This is when you have two seperate folders for client and server.

Else you can check [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-react-app-with-a-node-backend-the-complete-guide/) article

Comment: Yes I've already  checked that pages but didn't work for me, thank you any way!